# Resolving Composer merge conflicts when upgrading Symfony2 Standard Edition

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

My project is based off of the Symfony Standard Edition which I cloned from the [original Symfony SE repository](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/2.1). Symfony of course distributes its own `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files noting its dependencies.

I use the `master` branch for my project's development, and since starting the project have added my own project's dependencies to `composer.json` and locked them with `composer.lock`.

But now it's time to update my project to use Symfony SE 2.1.3.

I have the Symfony Standard Edition repo added as a git remote:

```
git remote add symfonyse git://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard.git
```

And I can merge in the latest changes from the `symfonyse` repository 2.1 branch to get the latest 2.1 developments:

```
git pull symfonyse 2.1
```

After pulling there of course are merge conflicts because I have modified `composer.json` with my own dependencies, and `composer.lock` was previously locked to my old dependencies.

But the `composer.lock` now in conflict is trying to merge the latest Symfony2 SE locked dependencies into my own project's locked dependencies (which includes my deps and Symfony 2.1.0's deps). Manually merging this would be very tedious!

What is the best way to resolve these conflicts in `composer.lock`?

Should I disregard the merge conflicts in `composer.lock` by doing `git checkout -- composer.lock` which reverts `composer.lock` back to its contents before I initiated the merge? I figure I could then run `composer update` for each dependency Symfony2 SE requires that has been updated in the new `composer.json` changes I just merged in.

Or should I accept all changes being merged in with `composer.lock`, commit them, then simply update ALL of my project dependencies by running `composer update`? This would essentially generate a brand new lock file anyway with locks for Symfony 2.1.3 and my own dependencies. I'm just not sure if I need the upstream updates to the lock file if I'm also getting the newest `composer.json` changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the best/ideal case is if you have somewhat stable requirements (not full of dev-master..), then you can just rm the composer.lock (or git checkout) and run update to make sure you get latest dependencies of everything.

If that's not possible, then you can also just revert the changes from upstream, and `composer update <specific packages>` to bring them up to speed. That is however error prone and tedious, so I think the best really is to make sure you have strict enough dependencies in your project that you can run composer update without fear.